# rn keyboard aware scroll view when press input then it scrolls a little bit up

Tags: react-native, expo

if I scroll down and press on input then my scroll position scrolls a little bit up. Every time when I press a button my scroll position goes up. How can I prevent this when I press that the scroll position remains the same?

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView 
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled' 
  contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}} 
  alwaysBounceVertical={false}
>
```